# Missing dcu while migrating delphi5 to delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am migrating my existing delphi5 applications to delphi7. While Compiling I am getting bellow error.

```
BRLookup not found
TMultLang not found
TBRListView not found
TDBBRCompanyName not found
TBRQuery not found
TBRCompanyLogo not found
TBRDateEdit not found
TBRCompanyLogo not found
TBRDescription not found
```

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)): "thanks", your name and "kindly advice" should never be part of a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check the search path of the D5 project - you can either open the project options in the D5 IDE or open *<ProjectName>*.dof in a text editor and look for a line SearchPath=... You probably find the directory where the missing units are. If you're lucky you have the sources or at least D7 DCUs. If you only have D5 DCUs, see [MBo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29137902/1431618).

Answer (score 3):

Old program uses 3rd party components/libraries (and they don't seem well-known ones).
You either have to find the sources of these libraries, or rewrite all the program using standard components.